# How to take screenshot from terminal

Tags: command-line, termux

I am writing a python script to process an image. I need to take automated screenshots. How can i do that with some kind of command ? No root acces. I am using termux and terminal emulator.

Comment: I did try imagemagick but it gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need elevated privileges, at least of user 2000 (shell) or higher. Since the Android is not rooted, your best bet is to get adb running in [wireless mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6949/96277) in your device. You would also have [to load](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200010/96277) a compatible adb binary for your Android to connect to localhost via adb.

Once this have been achieved, run

```
adb shell screencap /sdcard/FILE_NAME.png
```

Comment: Is this exclusively from adb? I tried from the actual phone (on 2 different devices) with a terminal app with `$ screencap test.png` and it generates a 0 byte file. The folder is writable, for example `echo hello > test.txt` does create a 6 byte file

Comment: Yes. You need adb. User installed (unprivileged) apps cannot capture screen without using [dedicated API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection).