# How to make a screenshot using Termux

Tags: screenshots, termux

When I am using Termux may I send a command to create and save a smartphone screenshot in /sdcard/DCIM ?

Comment: Related for non-rooted device: [How to take screenshot from terminal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202603/how-to-take-screenshot-from-terminal)

Comment: adb should be executed in a computer terminal connected to phone, I'm asking a way to do that from smartphone using Termux .

Comment: Taking screenshot requires permission `READ_FRAME_BUFFER`. It has protection level `signature|privileged`, so cannot be granted to non-system apps (at least without root). // `adb` can be executed on phone without PC if you have root access (also sometimes without root access).

Comment: I can't see adb as an available command when I login in terminal using Termux. How can I execute adb from Termux ?

Comment: [How to run adb and fastboot commands from Termux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216474/218526)